# How to display entity label using entity reference field checkbox form display

Tags: 8, entities

I am working with Drupal 8. And I want to create a field of entity_reference type. The field has a reference to context_question entity. And the field is displayed fine, but without any description beside the check boxes.

The context_question entity has a label field and I want exactly the label be displayed beside the checkbox in my first entity. What should I change in the code? Or do I need to create the fieldFormatter?

```
$fields['context_question'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Context Question'))
  ->setDescription(t('Reference to context-question-type'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'context_question')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',   
    'format' => 'label',
    'weight' => 15,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'options_buttons',
    'weight' => 15,
  ))
  ->setCardinality(1000)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `context_question` is your custom entity or coming from a contrib module?

There are two options:

1. Add `label` key to `context_question` entity definition under `entity_keys` so that `Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\DefaultSelection` pick it up. See [Aggregator item](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.1/core/modules/aggregator/src/Entity/Item.php#L39) for reference.
2. Add a `@EntityReferenceSelection` plugin. You have to define one. Check [TermSelection](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.1/core/modules/taxonomy/src/Plugin/EntityReferenceSelection/TermSelection.php) for how it is implemented for terms. It looks like this:

[image: Term reference with options_button form display]